# PHP: Login using external file

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I am having an issue using an external login file. Basically I would like to go to an external login php page and validate the form. Once the form has been validated then I would like to redirect back to the previous page and start a session. The issue I am having is that my session does not start (i.e. it does not change the login form to a log out button). My code is down below. Thanks in advance.

Index.php

```
<?
    session_start();
    include('phpFunctions/databaseConnect.php');
    include('phpFunctions/reusableFunctions.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Unnamed classifieds site</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/formValidation.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="login">
                <? if(isset($_GET['error'])){$error = $_GET['error'];} ?>
                <span id="error_message" class="error"><? if(isset($error)){echo $error;} ?><span id="login_error"></span></span>
                <? login(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="mainLogo">
                <? mainLogo(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="search_form">
                <span id="error_message" class="error"><span id="search_error"></span></span>
                <? search(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <? footer(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Login.php

```
<?

    include('phpFunctions/databaseConnect.php');
    $error = array();

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($email) || empty($password)){
        $error[] = 'Please fill in the form!';
    }else if(!preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/',$email)){
        $error[] = 'Your email is not in the correct format!';
    }else if(strlen($password) < 6){
        $error[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long!';
    }else{
        $hashPass = md5($password);

        $query_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$hashPass'") or die(mysql_error());
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_user);

        if($num_rows == 1){
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_user)){
               $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
               header('Location:index.php');
           }
        }else{
            $error[] = 'Sorry no user with that email or password!';
        }
    }

    if(!empty($error)){
        foreach($error as $key => $values){
            $error_message.= "$values";
        }

        header('Location: index.php?error='.  urlencode($error_message));
    }

?>
```

Comment: do print_r($_SESSION) and check is session start?

Comment: is login page is included inside your index.php? because what i am seeing is you are storing errors in one page(variable not in session) and you are echoing it in index.php. If both the page are different then there must be some errors which cant be forwarded to your index.php, what is inside login function

Comment: So i tried the way you suggested with including login.php into index but firefox would not let me view my page stating too many redirects to the same page. The way I am doing it now allows me to pass errors back by using the $_GET. I tried that with session id as well but the issue now is people can enter a session id into the browse and view other people's accounts.

Comment: SO i figured it out. The issue was I was not starting a session in login.php. So it should be session_start() then $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'], then the redirect.

Comment: i think you may place datbaseConnect in all files so better recommend to place it in databaseConnect or some config file